# Pyinstaller kivy exe R6034 - "An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly."

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Attempting to package up a simple Kivy GUI application (just a text file parser) into a single .exe for Windows on Win 7. When run using Kivy on my local machine (not packaged) it works fine and does everything I need it to. When I try to run the packaged version, I'm coming up with a runtime error: "R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly."

This is the console stdout and stderr I get when running the exe from powershell (along with the error dialog that pops up with the R6034 msg):

```
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[ERROR             ] [filechooser ] win32file module is missing
[ERROR             ] [filechooser ] we cant check if a file is hidden or not
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.3621>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.20 - Build 10.18.10.3621>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[WARNING           ] [Image       ] Unable to load image 

<C:\Users\ZM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI124202\kivy_install\data\glsl\default.png>

[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core", line 65, in core_select_lib
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.window.window_sdl2", line 121, in 
__init__
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.window", line 616, in __init__
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.window.window_sdl2", line 188, in 
create_window
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.window", line 769, in create_window
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 751, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ 
(kivy\graphics\instructions.c:10270)
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.image", line 511, in __init__
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.image", line 699, in _set_filename
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.image", line 429, in load
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.image", line 197, in __init__
  File "C:\tmp\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\tsapp\build\main\out00-PYZ.pyz\kivy.core.image.img_sdl2", line 42, in load

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

The only image that I'm using in the application is one for the background, but even when I comment the section that loads the file out and re-package it gives me the same error msg.

Here's my spec file that I'm using:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import install_hooks
import os
install_hooks(globals())

a = Analysis(['C:\\tmp\\tsapp\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\tmp\\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x64\\tsapp'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             runtime_hooks=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          icon='C:\\tmp\\tsapp\\media\\excavator.ico'
          )

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               Tree("C:\\tmp\\tsapp"),
               Tree(
                   [f for f in os.environ.get('KIVY_SDL2_PATH', '').split(';') if 'bin' in f][0]),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='main'
               )
```

I suspect that this is just something on my windows install that I haven't figured out yet - I'm not the most familiar with packaging for Windows.

Comment: It seems pyinstaller is not able to find the path to the SDL2 libs. Try to include the path to these libs manually in hidden paths.